# Other language character issue on websphere

Tags: linux, file, utf-8, websphere, special-characters

In our application, temp folder in linux system is getting filled because one of the file created in loop. Reason being the file name have special character 'ñ'.
So the system is not able to understand that character. Application is deployed in websphere 8.5.5.12 and the problem is only for linux not for windows. I think this problem is related to encoding/linux/websphere so tried below ways:

1. Adding JVM arguments in WAS as below:
   `-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8`
   `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
2. Changing Locale as:
   `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
3. Changing value in `encoding.properties` located at  `<PROFILE_ROOT>/properties` from `en=ISO-8859-1` to `en=UTF-8`
4. Replace `File.io` to `File.nio`
5. Setting encoding as below:
    `System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
    System.setProperty("sun.jnu.encoding","UTF-8");`
6. Setting UTF-8 from Eclipse and recompiling, redeploying on server.
7. Using string constructor as `new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")` to translate the text to 'UTF-8'.

Tried almost all the ways but not able to proceed further.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What's the location/type of the file causing this issue?

Comment: @wtlucy File is supposed to get created in /tmp/someFolder/ZipFile.zip and inside the zip there are one or more pdf files. ZipFile as well as pdf has that special character, causing " error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8"